# Como ter resposta de 'apt remove' via shell_exec com PHP ou Python?

Tags: php, python, shell-script

Com o comando shell_exec eu consigo ter uma resposta caso o resultado do comando executado for um unico texto:

```
shel_exec('dpkg -l > list-softwares-dpkg.txt');
```

Como ter a resposta (em PHP ou Python, o precisaria de outro comando ter uma resposta ?) da execução de um comando quando a resposta não é um texto unico como no exemplo:

```
shel_exec('apt remove pacote_exemplo > removed-package.txt');
```

**Obs**
No exemplo ele executa e desinstala, porem não consigo saber se o comando foi executado ou não.

Comment: Já tentou algo semelhante a este, https://stackoverflow.com/q/8217613/1452488?

Comment: Consegui com a versão 3.5: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Edit¹.. Não funciona assim também, só do mesmo jeito com resposta estática, tipo, no apt remove, preciso responder o 'y' em alguns casos, ai que não to conseguindo

Comment: Já tentou passar a opção `-y` no comando? Ela automaticamente assumirá *sim* para qualquer possível questionamento do comando.

Comment: Em Java, você tem as streams de input, output e output de erro. E qualquer outro file descriptor relacionado ao processo, eu acho. Não tem nada disso no Python/PHP? (Claro, a opção de linha de comando `-y` é a melhor hipótese)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O problema era em capturar o que havia acontecido na execução do script, executando o script via php ou python, consegui contornar executando o comando em uma conexão ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `popen` diferente do `exec` e similares pode interagir semelhante a um *handler* de I/O de arquivo, **provavelmente** com ele irá conseguir pegar a "saída" toda, por exemplo:

```
$response = '';
$handle = popen('apt-get remove ' . $package . ' 2>&1', 'r');

if ($handle) {
    while (feof($handle) === false) {
        $response .= fgets($handle); //Pega até encontrar uma quebra de linha
    }

    pclose($handle);
} else {
    die('Erro ao executar o programa');
}

if (empty($response)) {
    die('Resposta voltou vazia');
}

var_dump($response);
```

Um exemplo com `ping` (que é algo que retorna a saída um a um):

```
<?php
$response = '';
$handle = popen('ping 127.0.0.1', 'r');

if ($handle) {
    while (feof($handle) === false) {
        $response .= fgets($handle); //Pega até encontrar uma quebra de linha
    }

    pclose($handle);
} else {
    die('Erro ao executar o programa');
}

if (empty($response)) {
    die('Resposta voltou vazia');
}

var_dump($response);
```

Se quiser indo exibindo o resultado diretamente na saída (output) faça o `echo` dentro do `while`, assim:

```
<?php
$response = '';
$handle = popen('ping 127.0.0.1', 'r');

if ($handle) {
    while (feof($handle) === false) {
        echo fgets($handle); //Pega até encontrar uma quebra de linha
    }

    pclose($handle);
} else {
    die('Erro ao executar o programa');
}
```

O interessante desta forma é que você já pode pegar parte da resposta e com um `stripos` ou `preg_match` detectar se o comando esta esperando tipo Y/N para confirmar algo e customizar você mesmo para situação que desejar, por exemplo supondo que rodou o `apt-get remove` e no terminal fosse exibido algo como:

> Do you want to continue [Y/N]

O `while` iria travar no `fgets` que contém este comando e neste momento você poderia usar um `fwrite`, algo como:

> **Nota:** mudando o segundo parametro para `a+`, que abre para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no final do handle.

```
$handle = popen('apt-get remove ' . $package . ' 2>&1', 'a+');

if ($handle) {
    while (feof($handle) === false) {
        $response = trim(fgets($handle));

        if (stripos($response, 'do you want to continue') !== false) {
            fwrite($handle, "Y\n");// O \n é para enviar a quebra de linha que creio ser necessária para disparar
        }
    }

    pclose($handle);
} else {
    die('Erro ao executar o programa');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada foi em PHP, utilizando a classe **SSH2** do pacote **phplibsec** pra executar o comando.

Segue exemplo:

```
    $input = 'apt-get remove ' . $package . ' -y';
    $ssh = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2('localhost');
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
        exit('Erro ao logar');
    }
    echo json_encode($ssh->exec($input));
```

No exemplo, conecta-se ao ssh do servidor (no caso eu mesmo), e executo o comando, 'echo' printa a resposta que viria ao executar no terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta simples, segue a baixo.

```
shel_exec('apt remove pacote_exemplo > removed-package.txt'; echo $?);
```

a variável **$?** retorna o código de retorno do último comando executado.
Se o código de retorno for diferente de **0** tem algum problema no comando, ai vc deve analizar o código de retorno.